# SQL Add a column with value of number 1 to last row but not as primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I add a column with value of number 1....n until the last row to existing table but not as primary key

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your existing table, zsing CTE create a temporary result set that includes a single column containing the row number for each row in the original table.

The row number is generated using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, which assigns a unique, sequential number to each row in the result set. The `SET` statement is then used to add a new column to the original table, with each value in the column set to the corresponding row number from the temporary result set.

Example:

```
-- Add new column
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD RowNumber INT

-- Set values of new column to 1 to n
;WITH CTE AS 
(
     SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
     FROM 
         MyTable
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET RowNumber = RN
```

This process helps you to add sequential numbers to your existing table, without having to manually update each row.